# on Ubuntu running 'gem install taps' gives ERROR: ... (NoMethodError) ... '<<' for #<Bundler::SpecSet:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror, taps

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 using Ruby 1.9.2 with RVM and RubyGems 1.8.5 and when I run

```
gem install taps
```

I get

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `<<' for #<Bundler::SpecSet:0x000000020fbc50>
```

I can successfully migrate my db with

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

I'm trying to install taps so that I can run

```
heroku db:push
```

which gives the error

```
Taps Load Error: no such file to load -- taps/operation
You may need to install or update the taps gem to use db commands.
On most systems this will be:

sudo gem install taps
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm reaaally new to rails but have had my fair amount of similar errors, so let me have a shot at it..

how about adding

```
gem "taps", "~> 0.3.23"
```

to your gemfile, and then running (in your app root folder...)

```
bundle install
```

Another little thing: Remember NOT to use sudo IF you are working with RVM as it will install gems as root but not at your home folder (and thus making your gemsets disorganized), OK, hope it helps. [Check my Source](http://rubygems.org/gems/taps)

PD: good luck on dev with Natty, i got tired of it and downgraded to Ubuntu Maverick Meerkat

Comment: Awesome!  That worked.  Thank you!  I had tried something similar earlier but hadn't used the "~>" and it didn't work.  Thanks for putting me back on course.

Comment: great.. to avoid these kind of errors, I always check [Rubygems](http://rubygems.org) prior to installing ANY gem, cheers and happy coding